# org.w3c.dom.DOMException: Only one root element allowed in android xml parsing

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have a method in which i pass the xml and it returns the parsed document.In some devices i got the above shown error.(the xml contains only one root element actually)

```
public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);     //i got the error here
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return doc;
    }
```

starting of xml is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
        xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
        xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
        xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
        xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
        >

<channel>
```

and the end

```
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: It would be good if we can see also the xml file. Especially right after the error occurred. Theoretically this should work, so please log out the xml if an error occurs to be able to check its content. Furthermore, what kind of devices are those that cannot parse the xml?

Comment: @Blehi its too large .i'll post the beginning and ending here

Comment: It looks OK to me.